# google.maps.places.Autocomplete call on blur, results in "Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Here is the error I get running following code:

Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('bodyOfWater'));
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
 //On select of the location
 google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
  var place = places.getPlace();
  alert(place.geometry.location.lat());
 });
 
 // Trigger search on blur
 /*=====================*/
 /* PROBLEM IN FOLLOWING CODE*/
 /*=====================*/
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('bodyOfWater'), 'blur', function() {
  var place = places.getPlace();
  alert(place.geometry.location.lat());;
 });
});
</script>
```

First part works properly when I actually select a place from google, but when I try to trigger same action on blur, looks like that I do not get place back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The places API is asynchronous.  You can't get the result until it comes back from the server (when the `place_changed` event fires).

Comment: So there is no way to trigger same event? I need to do this if user just typed something in a box and din not select anything.

Comment: No, look at this example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places . First you send a request, and you add a callback.  When Google maps is ready with the request, it will trigger the callback, and give you the result.  That's the javascript way (like Ajax does the same thing).

Comment: ok got it. How then I trigger place_changed event when user entered the palace but did not select one from the list?

Comment: You can't trigger that event (well you can, but it doesn't do anything useful without the server request/response), it needs to be triggered by the response coming back from the server indicating the data is available.

Comment: Had to find work around. In case it becomes available let me know.

Comment: this problem solved or not,i have suffering from same problem